# Working with the constructor parameters in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

As shown in the image below, I need to manipulate the input parameter of the constructor that is `commandsList` but it gave an unknown variable, even with using the `this.` with it.

I wounder that it accepted this parameter and `passed it` as an input paramter for another method in the same class, that forced me to write a separate method to handle the few lines I need.

Any help?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to make it an instance variable. Currently it is only a parameter. You can create auto instance variables from constructors like this

```
constructor(private commandslist: ICommandList) {
   console.log(this.commandslist);
}
```

Or if you prefer to have it declared explicitly:

```
private commandslist: ICommandList;

constructor(commandslist: ICommandList) {
    this.commandslist = commandslist;
    console.log(this.commandslist);
}
```

Comment: Although I usually prefer more-explicit.  I like the first approach in this case.  It's soo clean, and TS takes care of the rest.

Comment: FYI I think they're officially called "parameter properties", not "auto instance variables".  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html